# How do I return column headers when there are no rows returned with Invoke-Sqlcmd?

Tags: sql, powershell, sqlcmd

When executing a query using `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, if no rows are returned, the result is just `$null`.

I wondering if it's possible to still return the column headers, but with no data. This would make it consistent with a query which did return rows.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: After trying a few things, I don't how this would be possible with invoke-sqlcmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a null back try this query:

```
select [COLUMN_NAME] from information_schema.columns where TABLE_NAME='TABLENAME'
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing (although I used `[sys].[columns]` instead). It doesn't really do what I wanted though, because I have to separately parse this output and pivot it into the correct format.

Answer (score -1):

Check for $null - if $null then call this query:

```
   set fmtonly on
   select * from yourTable where 1=0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting no rows back and in PowerShell it's still returning $null.